# Creating cover traffic by calling random urls - Javascript loop to decrement float

Tags: javascript, random

This is a `for`-loop which runs once for each step with `i>1` and maybe for `0 <= i <= 1`.

```
var i;
var prob_ = 3.5;
for ( i = prob_; i >= 0; i -= 1 ) {
    if ( i > 1 || withProbability(i) ) {
        loadHttp(randomUrl());
    }
}
```

with

```
function withProbability(chance) {
    return Math.random() < chance;
}
```

JsLint gave me a `for`-loop error. **Is this code ok despite that warning, or should this `for`-loop be changed to some other looping construct?**

#### Background

`prob_` is a ratio between fake actions and real actions. The loop is triggered once for each real action. If `prob_` is greater than 1, the fake action is done. If it is in between 0 and 1, it is considered a probability and thus maybe a fake action follows.

This is a case where it was not clear how to replace the `for`-loop with a `forEach`, as is often recommended. Maybe ES6 tail recursion could be used...

#### More context

```
function loadHttp(toLoad) {
    require("sdk/page-worker").Page({
        contentURL: toLoad
    });
}
```

*The implementation of `randomUrl()`* is rather lengthy and does not relate to the question. It determines a statistically probable length of a HTML (or embedded object like js, img, css, ...) site, then does a lookup for the next bigger URL in a hardcoded list. It is supposed that the randomness will confuse someone who watches for traffic patterns.

#### Full class *coverTraffic.js*

This is initialized via

```
const coverTraffic = require('./coverTraffic.js');
coverTraffic.setLoader(require('./load.js'));
```

with *load.js* containing similar to `loadHttp` as above. It is triggered via

```
function loads(URL) {
    if ( _.contains(activeHosts, URL.host) ) { // has already started
        coverTraffic.loadNext();
    } else {
        activeHosts.push(URL.host);
        coverTraffic.start();
    }
}
exports.loads = URL => loads(URL);
```

which is called whenever the browser loads a new URL.

```
"use strict";

exports.DOC = 'creates cover traffic, up to predetermined parameters';

const { setTimeout } = require("sdk/timers");

const coverUrl = require("./coverUrl.js");
const stats = require("./stats.js");

/** overhead of dummy traffic -1; 1.5 has overhead of 50% */
const FACTOR = 1.5;

var load;

var site_ = {};
var pad_ = {};
var prob_;

function setLoader(load_param) {
    load = load_param;
}
exports.setLoader = (load_param) => setLoader(load_param);

/** a website is loaded by the user. covertraffic determines a target
 * feature vector and adds to the load to approximate the target.
 */
function start() {
    site_ = {};
    pad_ = {};

    site_.html = stats.htmlSize(1); // td: buffer known sites in bloomfilter
    pad_.html = stats.htmlSize(FACTOR) - site_.html;
    site_.num_embedded = stats.numberEmbeddedObjects(1); // td: see above
    pad_.num_embedded = stats.numberEmbeddedObjects(FACTOR) - site_.num_embedded;
    prob_ = pad_.num_embedded / site_.num_embedded;

    //    setTimeout(loadNext, stats.parsingTime());
    load.http(coverUrl.sized(pad_.html));
}
exports.start = start;

function loadNext() {
    var i;
    if ( pad_.num_embedded > 0 ) {
    for ( i = prob_; i >= 0; i -= 1 ) {
        if ( i > 1 || stats.withProbability(i) ) {
        load.http(coverUrl.sized(stats.embeddedObjectSize()));
        pad_.num_embedded -= 1;
        }
    }
    } else {
    console.log("cover traffic empty, num: " + pad_.num_embedded);
    }
}
exports.loadNext = loadNext;
```

The `stats` module provides statistical distributions, the `load`-module just loading a URL as described above.

Comment: See [What topics can I ask about here?](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) If your code is not working correctly then the question is off-topic for this site

Comment: @Phrancis: but it is working correctly, right?

Comment: Looks like a good question to me - provided you tested it... Although you might want to show what `doSomething()` is, rather than giving an example.

Comment: @Pimgd: there are even  unit tests (I have not checked the coverage, though)

Comment: @Pimgd: `doSomething` basically does a HTTP request and decrements a counter. It does not use `i` internally. Including the whole code with two more modules would deviate from a minimal example. If you recommend posting it, just leave a comment.

Comment: I would recommend posting it because Code Review prefers production-style code, and does not want minimal examples. I believe your approach is flawed, but I cannot say this because I don't know what you are going to do with `doSomething()`. Normally this would invalidate answers and is not done, but I don't mind for this instance and will update my answer accordingly after your edit if need be.

Comment: @Pimgd: thank you. All the code is now in the (lengthy) question.

Comment: I'd like this discuss this question with you [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor) if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem JSLint is pointing at is that you usually iterate with an index that is an integer. If you were to have an array, you couldn't use `i` to access the array elements, because if `i` is big enough, rounding issues may cause you to skip elements or see elements twice!

What I'd recommend is that you just use `i` as integer, and then once the for loop is done, check if there is an additional chance to roll for. That way, you don't have to worry about floating point rounding errors accumulating.

Another way you could do it is first roll, and then if you roll high enough, up `i` by 1. That way you only have one place where you run your code.

So like this:

```
var chance = i % 1;
if (chance !== 0 && withProbability(chance)){
    i = Math.ceil(i);
} else {
    i = Math.floor(i);
}
//for loop goes here
```

Comment: One more question: Would you also do an `else { i = Math.floor(i); }` or just keep `i` as a non_Integer otherwise?

Comment: @user you're absolutely right, you do want to convert i to integer.